# nodejs/Mac and open files limit

Tags: node.js

I have written a program that recursively reads files in one directory, modifies them and writes them into another directory. Everytime I run that program, it croakes after a couple of hundred iterations. I just run it again, and it seems to complete the task.

Either nodejs or Mac OS X or, most likely, nodejs-on-Mac-OS-X, seems to have some kind of limit on the number of files that can be opened at one time. Searching around, I see that a solution is to use something like `ulimit -n 10480` and all will be well. Is that the right way? Instinctively, I'd rather not tinker with my system settings and rather modify my program to work within the limits.

An observation: Earlier I used to use Perl to do the task I've described above, and I never had a problem. I am assuming it was because I was opening, transforming, then closing the file, and then moving along. In nodejs, using `async` mode, I have no way of closing a file *before* going on to the next file. If I do the task in `sync` mode, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the async library with the limit commands to limit the number of files processed to a certain number. For example :

```
async.eachLimit(files, 1000, function (file, next) {
    processFile(file, next);
}, done);
```

If you wish to process a single file before going to the next one just use eachSeries.

```
async.eachSeries(files, function (file, next) {
    processFile(file, next);
}, done);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, macOS (and possibly every UNIX variant) has a limit on the number of open files, and yes, Perl didn't have that problem for the reason that you mention.

`ulimit` is not a system setting the way that you seem to think about it. `ulimit` applies to the current process and is copied to its children processes when you start them, meaning that if you raise the limit in a process, you're not impacting the other processes, within the boundaries that if you're changing the limits on some globally-constrained resource like physical memory usage, you might be starving other programs. In other words, if you run `ulimit -n 10480` in a shell, effects only last until you exit that shell.

On macOS, the actual upper ceiling of system-wide open files is given by the command `sysctl kern.maxfiles`. Regardless of `ulimit` settings, opening files will fail if you try to open more than that on your entire system at once. On my system, it's 12288. This is the "system setting" that tinkering with can have more lasting effects: raising it increases the static amount of memory that the kernel needs (by amounts unknown to me), and lowering it can starve processes from file descriptors.

If your script is relatively short-lived, raising the file descriptor limit using `ulimit` is probably not a problem.

I don't know about node.js though, and maybe (almost certainly) it has facilities to start just a number of async tasks at a time, so you could also do that.